# Increase the LXD/LXC Btrfs loop file storage pool size

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, lxc, resizing, lxd

Our production container crashed because its LXC storage pool is out of space.

Here is `dh -h` from inside the container:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       82G   78G  2.0G  98% /
```

Here the same mount from the host system:

```
/dev/loop0       82G   78G  2.0G  98% /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default
```

I remember a year ago when I was setting this up, it asked me if 80GB for something that sounded unfamiliar would be enough, and because it did not say "container disk size" and said something else, I just thought I better trust the default option. Now I know it *is* the disk space limit.  How can I increase this limit now?

At the moment, I just cleaned some space urgently. The host machine actually has terabytes of disk space.

P.S. Sorry for complaining but documentation for LXC is one of the worst I've ever seen. It just does not make sense for a user like me.

P.P.S. I forgot that I actually use LXD, doh. The fact that I type `lxc` to do anything confused me.

**UPDATE:**
Intuitively, I figured this command could resize the storage pool:

```
# lxc storage set default size 200GB
```

But it fails with:

```
Error: The [size] properties cannot be changed for "btrfs" storage pools
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[LXD 5.13](https://web.archive.org/web/20230415052815/https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/lxd-5-13-has-been-released/16949), released 15 April 2023, added support for [growing existing loop file storage pools](https://web.archive.org/web/20230626213541/https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/latest/howto/storage_pools/#resize-a-storage-pool).

This is the template of the simple command to grow a storage pool `<pool_name>` to `<new_size>`:

```bash
lxc storage set <pool_name> size=<new_size>
```

For the resize in the question, this is what you would run:

```bash
lxc storage set default size=200G
```

---

## Old Answer

When this answer was first written on 17 September 2019, we had LXD 3.17, which didn't have a built-in way to resize Btrfs file-backed storage pools, so I came up with this workaround that should work on LXD versions below 5.13:

### Online Grow

#### One-Liner

Replace `default` with the name of the storage volume and `100G` with the new desired size:

```bash
grow_lxd_btrfs_file() { STORAGE_POOL="$1" ; NEW_SIZE="$2" ; STORAGE_POOL_SOURCE="$(lxc storage get "$STORAGE_POOL" source)" ; sudo truncate -s "$NEW_SIZE" "$STORAGE_POOL_SOURCE" ; STORAGE_POOL_LOOP_DEVICE="$(losetup -j "$STORAGE_POOL_SOURCE" | awk -F': ' '{print $1}' | head -1)" ; sudo losetup -c "$STORAGE_POOL_LOOP_DEVICE" ; LXD_PID=$(pgrep lxd | head -1) ; NS_MOUNT_POINT=$(sudo nsenter -t "$LXD_PID" -m -- findmnt -no target "$STORAGE_POOL_LOOP_DEVICE") ; sudo btrfs filesystem resize max "/proc/$LXD_PID/root/$NS_MOUNT_POINT" ; lxd sql global "UPDATE storage_pools_config SET value = '$NEW_SIZE' WHERE key = 'size' AND storage_pool_id IN (SELECT id FROM storage_pools WHERE name = '$STORAGE_POOL')" ; } \
grow_lxd_btrfs_file default 100G
```

#### Explanation

1. Set the variable `$STORAGE_POOL` to the name of your storage pool.  In your case, it is `default`:

   ```bash
   STORAGE_POOL=default
   ```
2. Set the variable `$NEW_SIZE` to the size you now want the storage pool to be:

   ```bash
   NEW_SIZE=100G
   ```

   <sup><sub>The value is an integer and optional unit (example: 10K is 10*1024).  Units are K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y (powers of 1024) or KB,MB,... (powers of 1000).</sub></sup>

   **Important:** The new size must be bigger than the current Btrfs file system size.  You will lose all data in your storage pool if the size is smaller.
3. On the host, find the path to the Btrfs storage pool file:

   ```bash
   STORAGE_POOL_SOURCE="$(lxc storage get "$STORAGE_POOL" source)"

   # Verify
   echo "$STORAGE_POOL_SOURCE"
   ```
4. Grow the Btrfs storage pool file:

   ```bash
   sudo truncate -s "$NEW_SIZE" "$STORAGE_POOL_SOURCE"
   ```
5. Make the loopback device(s) aware of the new size:

   ```bash
   STORAGE_POOL_LOOP_DEVICE="$(losetup -j "$STORAGE_POOL_SOURCE" |
                               awk -F': ' '{print $1}' |
                               head -1)"

   sudo losetup -c "$STORAGE_POOL_LOOP_DEVICE"
   ```
6. Get an LXD process ID so that we can enter its mount namespace later:

   ```bash
   LXD_PID=$(pgrep lxd | head -1)

   # Verify
   echo "$LXD_PID"
   ```
7. Get the online Btrfs mount point:

   ```bash
   NS_MOUNT_POINT=$(sudo nsenter -t "$LXD_PID" -m -- \
                    findmnt -no target "$STORAGE_POOL_LOOP_DEVICE")

   # Verify
   echo "$NS_MOUNT_POINT"
   ```
8. Finally, resize the Btrfs file system to the maximum possible size:

   ```bash
   sudo btrfs filesystem resize max "/proc/$LXD_PID/root/$NS_MOUNT_POINT"
   ```
9. For consistency, update the LXD database with the new size of the storage pool:

   ```bash
   lxd sql global "UPDATE storage_pools_config SET value = '$NEW_SIZE'
       WHERE
           key = 'size' AND
           storage_pool_id IN
               (SELECT id FROM storage_pools WHERE name = '$STORAGE_POOL')"

   # Verify
   lxd sql global "SELECT * FROM storage_pools_config
       WHERE storage_pool_id IN
           (SELECT id FROM storage_pools WHERE name = '$STORAGE_POOL')"
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! Two questions though not covered in your answer that came to me after I read it: 1) is there a way to back up the storage before I attempt doing this? 2) do I need to stop LXD or it's containers before the proceeding?

Comment: @exebook: (1) There are various ways to back up an LXD server and its containers. See [here](https://lxd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backup/) for a general overview. You might find the `lxc export` command useful. (2) That said, I designed the "Online Grow" instructions specifically for growing the storage pool without any downtime.

Comment: It worked, can't thank you enough. This script should really be included in lxd as `lxc grow default`.

Comment: Works great! When using the LXD snap I had to set `STORAGE_POOL_SOURCE` manually as `storage get` returns an empty string: `STORAGE_POOL_SOURCE=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/disks/local.img`

Comment: For me `btrfs filesystem resize max [...]` fails with `ERROR: not a btrfs filesystem: [...]` – it works though when using `nsenter --mount=/run/snapd/ns/lxd.mnt /snap/current/lxd/bin/btrfs filesystem resize max [...]` as detailed [here](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/snap-lxd-cannot-resize-default-btrfs-storage-pool/9583/15)

Comment: > Important: The new size must be bigger than the current Btrfs file system size. You will lose all data in your storage pool if the size is smaller.

I had accidentally copy pasted and , before changing  the 100G to +100G  now whole file image trashed. 
It had 800 GB and  i managed to interrupted before everything is truncated . 
Now i am left with a corrupted image  file..
Anyway to restore it? And the  i was suppose to change `defalult` to `btrfs` now effected storage is default which is zfs not the storage with btrfs.

Comment: @PhyoArkarLwin: You'll need to restore from a backup.

Answer (score 2):

This link gives instructions on resizing a btrfs pool, but the last command fails as mentioned by #lcnittl.

As lcnittl stated, you need to change the command to

`nsenter --mount=/run/snapd/ns/lxd.mnt /snap/lxd/current/bin/btrfs filesystem resize max /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/pool1/`

where pool1 is the said pool. if you try the "btrfs" command direct, it fails first off as the command cannot be found, then if you install via apt, it states its not a btrfs pool.

The above command seems to point to a brtfs command that comes with lxd rather than as a separate install and you need to use this command instead